# Como sumar una columna en especifico en un Datatable

Tags: javascript, html

Debo sumar las columnas 3 y 4 con este código que dejo abajo pero lo hace en la calumna 5, 7 y 9

```
$('#DatosNomina').DataTable({
        "paging": false,
        "autoWidth": true,
        "footerCallback": function (row, data, start, end, display) {
            var api = this.api();
            nb_cols = api.columns().nodes().length;
            var j = 3;
            while (j < nb_cols) {
                var pageTotal = api
                    .column(j, {
                        page: 'current'
                    })
                    .data()
                    .reduce(function (a, b) {
                        return Number(a) + Number(b);
                    }, 0);
                // Update footer
                $(api.column(j).footer()).html(pageTotal);
                j++;
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De esta forma se pueden sumar columnas especificas

```
$("#cashSheet").dataTable({
    "footerCallback": function(row, data, start, end, display){
        var api = this.api(), data;
        var intval = function(i){
            return typeof i === 'string' ?
            i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1:
            typeof i === 'number' ?
            i : 0;
        };
        total = api
            .column( 3 )
            .data()
            .reduce(function(a, b){
                return intval(a) + intval(b);
            }, 0 );
        pageTotal = api
            .column( 3, {page: 'current'} )
            .data()
            .reduce(function(a, b){
                return intval(a) + intval(b);
            }, 0 );
        $(api.column( 3 ).footer() ).html(
            ''+pageTotal +' ( '+ total + ' total)'
        );
        total = api
            .column( 4 )
            .data()
            .reduce(function(a, b){
                return intval(a) + intval(b);
            }, 0 );
        pageTotal = api
            .column( 4, {page: 'current'} )
            .data()
            .reduce(function(a, b){
                return intval(a) + intval(b);
            }, 0 );
        $(api.column( 4 ).footer() ).html(
            ''+pageTotal +' ( '+ total + ' total)'
        );
    }
});
```